# How to fix an 'index out of range' error in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to write en auxiliar function which is counting the occurences of every integer between 0 and li[-1], saying that li is a sorted list.

I can't see my mistake... I know what this kind of error message means, but I don't know where the variable j is reaching a limit.

```
def aux_compter_occurence(li):
    resu = [0] * (li[-1]+1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < (li[-1] + 1):
        while li[j] == i:
            resu[i] += 1
            j +=1
        i += 1
    return resu
```

For example, with the input [2,4,4,4,7,8,8], the output should be [0,0,1,0,3,0,0,1,2]

Comment: Hi mariecurry. Typically, this is the kind of question you can answer yourself by using the debugger or by using strategic `print` statements. The error message will probably contain a line number, and possibly show the exact location of the error. While it's great that you're getting answers, this question is pretty specific to your exact code; it's like we're doing your homework or acting as your personal testers. I understand it's your first question, as does everyone else who can see it. Nobody important is mad, and you'll get better at it. This is just FYI. Welcome to SO! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can be passed an iteratable and will count each occurance, we can then use a simple comprehension to generate the result

```
import collections

def aux_compter_occurence(li):
    counts = collections.Counter(li)
    return [counts.get(i, 0) for i in range(li[-1] + 1)]
```

Or if you wish to use the previous method of incrementing the values in a list, you already know the index in the list because it is equal to the integer value. We can simplify quite a bit

```
def aux_compter_occurence(li):
    resu = [0] * (li[-1] + 1)
    for i in li:
        resu[i] += 1
    return resu
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "j < len(li)" to your code and now it works.

```
def aux_compter_occurence(li):
    resu = [0] * (li[-1]+1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < (li[-1] + 1):
        while j < len(li) and li[j] == i:
            resu[i] += 1
            j +=1
        i += 1
    return resu
```